# Why <textarea> HTML tag does not allow for display of PHP echo variable?

Tags: php, html

I wrote the CRUD script whic allows edit of a MySQL database record. I want the edit file to display textarea with database cell contents. For some reason it doesn't do that. What changes to the code do I need?

```php
<?php // including the database connection file
include_once("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['update'])) {   

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['id']);     
    $vrstakontakta = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['vrstakontakta']);   $biljeska =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['biljeska']);     $telefon =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['telefon']); $email =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']); $website =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['website']);
$nazivorganizacije = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['nazivorganizacije']); $imeosobe =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['imeosobe']); $zemlja =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['zemlja']);
$profesijaradnomjesto = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,
$_POST['profesijaradnomjesto']); $proizvodi =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['proizvodi']); $projekat =
mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['projekat']);




        //updating the table        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE
kontakti_autobusnooglasavanje SET vrstakontakta='$vrstakontakta',
biljeska='$biljeska',telefon='$telefon',  email='$email', 
website='$website',  nazivorganizacije='$nazivorganizacije', 
imeosobe='$imeosobe',  zemlja='$zemlja', 
profesijaradnomjesto='$profesijaradnomjesto',  proizvodi='$proizvodi',
projekat='$projekat' WHERE id=$id");
                //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php      header("Location: index.php");

} ?> <?php //getting id from url $id = $_GET['id'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id $result =
mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM kontakti_autobusnooglasavanje
WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     $vrstakontakta =
$res['vrstakontakta'];  $biljeska = $res['biljeska'];   $telefon =
$res['telefon'];        $email = $res['email'];         $website =
$res['website'];        $nazivorganizacije = $res['nazivorganizacije'];
        $imeosobe = $res['imeosobe'];       $zemlja = $res['zemlja'];
        $profesijaradnomjesto = $res['profesijaradnomjesto'];       $proizvodi =
$res['proizvodi'];      $projekat = $res['projekat'];

} ?> <html> <head>      <title>Edit Data</title> </head>

<body>  <a href="index.php">Home</a>    <br/><br/>      <form name="form1"
method="post" action="edit.php">        <table border="0">
                <tr> 
                <td>Vrsta kontakta</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="vrstakontakta" value="<?php echo $vrstakontakta;?>"></td>          </tr>

                    <tr> 
                <td>Biljeska</td>
                <td>    <input type="text" name="biljeska" value="<?php echo $biljeska;?>"></td>


                <td> <textarea cols="60" name="biljeska" rows="20" value="<?php echo $biljeska;?>">   </textarea> </td>


                            </tr>
```

Comment: Textarea content goes between the opening and closing tags, not in a value attribute. E.g. `<textarea>Content goes here</textarea>`.

Comment: to be exact: `<textarea cols="60" name="biljeska" rows="20" ><?php echo $biljeska;?></textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly right but there is a gotcha with `<textarea>` it is a little bit different to an input. Instead of holding a value it wraps the value.

```
<textarea cols="60" name="biljeska" rows="20"><?php echo $biljeska;?></textarea>
```

Which is exactly what the comments are saying.

Notice also that in my example code there are no extra spaces. This is important. Because all characters between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` is the data. Your code currently has a number of spaces as the value data.

With a `<textarea>` and the `<pre>` tag white space (spaces, newlines, tabs, etc.) has meaning.